# Chemistry Vs. AutoMobile Industry

Tags: organic-chemistry

Well, it may not sound deeply related to chemistry but my question is to some chemistry-experts who knows bit about automobile industry.

I want to ask, if a person is getting graduated by having studied all the chemistry majors and he/she wants to get into any field related to automobile industry or cars to be precise. What would they be?

Which are the jobs one can join that are related to automobiles and at the same time demands a degree related to chemistry rather than mechanical engineering. I just suppose that chemistry is required in making cars efficient through fuel, as fuel science is all-chemistry but I need to know all the possible ways a person can get into automobiles having a chemistry degree. I hope it makes sense :)

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not about chemistry as a subject, so it is off-topic for [Chemistry.se]. I'm not sure if there is a site in the network, where it would be on topic.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン But it is a question about the practical *applications* of chemistry which is surely on topic.

Comment: @matt_black Maybe that would be an issue better discussed on meta. If I remember correctly we have relegated questions about careers to academia (when suitable) in the past. If it were on topic, I'd still say it is too broad and a bad fit for our site. But since I'm not making the decisions here, the question is still open, I just noted my concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to ask, if a person is getting graduated by having studied all the chemistry majors and he/she wants to get into any field related to automobile industry or cars to be precise. What would they be?

Paints, adhesives, polymers => Polymer Science/ Organic Chemistry. Adhesives is a big industry

Corrosion protection => Electrochemistry

Volatiles in new cars, fuel emissions, regulations => Gas chromatography/ analytical chemistry

Energy, fuel cells => Battery science, electrochemistry

Solar cells => Material science

Answer (score 1):

Of course the first thing to come to my mind is fuel technology. For example st1 makes [fuel from waste](https://www.st1.eu/about-st1/company-information/areas-operations/advanced-fuels-waste). I'm pretty sure that tire development also need chemistry in rubber compounds. In addition catalytic converter development needs chemistry because their purpose is to cause reactions.
So as a whole I would say that catalytic converter technology and fuel (maybe bio?) technology are your best bets.

Comment: As more cars go electric, battery-related chemistry is a big one as well.

Comment: Paint chemistry would be applicable too